# .saveWebPartChanges() always re-enables 'Display search box' to checked

Tags: web-part, csom, jsom

When I set JSLinks on WeParts with code:

```
   jsl.ctx.load(properties);
    properties.set_item('JSLink', JSLink);
    webpartDef.saveWebPartChanges();
```

#### It also resets the previously unchecked Display search box to CHECKED !?!

[image]

Comment: Looks like it resets when you don't change anything too, just running `webpartDef.saveWebPartChanges();` without any `set_item`